# I'm trying to store the image inside the uploads folder. But still it is giving the same error

Tags: node.js, path, storage, multer

Screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I'm trying to store the image inside the uploads folder.
As you guys can see I have configured the multer as well.
But still it is giving the same error.
Can anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslash after uploads in the destination i.e ('/uploads')

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, i saw that you're using `diskStorage` setting with `destination` field.

destination is used to determine within which folder the uploaded files should be stored. This can also be given as a string (e.g. '/tmp/uploads'). If no destination is given, the operating system's default directory for temporary files is used.

Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you.

You can solve this by putting the following block of code before multer

```
fs.mkdir('./uploads', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```